# Div changes after mouseover, Div not displaying

Tags: javascript, css

Well, i'm starting to write this webpage and i've run into a few problems that i just cannot quite find the answers to.

The basic idea of the code I have is:

1. Open menu when the mouse is on "explore webpage"
2. Menu "links" highlight on mouseover
3. When user clicks on menu item, the menu moves to the top of the page and the "link" stays highlighted until the user clicks a different link.
4. When the menu moves to the top, a div opens below, displaying the content for that section.

I am having two main problems.  Firstly, whenever I click on the menu item, it does not stay highlighted (number 3).  Secondly, the div is not opening below the menu after the click(number 4).  I would greatly appreciate any insight into these issues.

I am including all of my code, as I believe it is all relevant to my problems.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body
{
    background-color: #000000;
}
#container
{
    z-index: -1;
    background: #000000;
    width: 900px;
    height: 900px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -450px;
}
#explore
{
    z-index: 1;
    background: #000000;
    width: 300px;
    height: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 41.666%;
    left: 33.333%;
    opacity: 1;
}

#explore-text
{
    z-index: 1;
    color: #eb56bd;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 0%;
    opacity: 1;
}
.title
{
    z-index: 2;
    width: 300px;
    height: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 60px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000000;
    display: none;
}
#news
{
    background: #eb56bd;
    position: absolute;
    top: 41.666%;
    left: 33.333%;
}
#about
{
    background: #eb56bd;
    position: absolute;
    top: 41.666%;
    left: 0%;
}
#events
{
    background: #eb56bd;
    position: absolute;
    top: 41.666%;
    left: 66.666%;
}
.content
{
    z-index: 0;
    background: #b0408d;
    width: 900px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 21.666%;
    left: 0px;
    height : 900;
}
#news-content
{
    display: none;
}
#about-content
{
    display: none;
}
#events-content
{
    display: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="explore" onmouseover="overExplore()" onmouseout="outExplore()">
<div id="explore-text">Explore Webpage</div>
</div>
<div id="news" class="title" onmouseover="overTitle(news)" onmouseout="outTitle(news)" onclick="titleClick(news)">news</div>
<div id="about" class="title" onmouseover="overTitle(about)" onmouseout="outTitle(about)" onclick="titleClick(about)">about</div>
<div id="events" class="title" onmouseover="overTitle(events)" onmouseout="outTitle(events)" onclick="titleClick(events)">events</div>
<div id="news-content" class="content">

</div>
<div id="about-content" class="content">

</div>
<div id="events-content" class="content">

</div>
</div>
<script>
var titleClicked = false;
var isClicked;
var newsContent = document.getElementById('news-content');
var aboutContent = document.getElementById('about-content');
var eventsContent = document.getElementById('events-content');
var title = document.getElementsByTagName('title');
var news = document.getElementById('news');
var about = document.getElementById('about');
var events = document.getElementById('events');
var explore = document.getElementById('explore');
var exploreText = document.getElementById('explore-text');
function overExplore() {
    explore.style.width="900px";
    explore.style.left="0%";
    explore.style.background="#eb56bd";
    explore.style.cursor="pointer";
    explore.style.cursor="hand";
    explore.style.opacity="0";
    news.style.display="block";
    about.style.display="block";
    events.style.display="block";
}
function outExplore() {
    explore.style.width="300px";
    explore.style.left="33.333%";
    explore.style.background="#000000";
    exploreText.style.left="0%";
    exploreText.style.top="5px";
    explore.style.opacity="1";
    news.style.display="none";
    about.style.display="none";
    events.style.display="none";
}

function overTitle(div) {
    if (div!= isClicked) {
        div.style.background="#b0408d";
    }
    if (titleClicked == false) {
    div.style.display="block";
    news.style.display="block";
    about.style.display="block";
    events.style.display="block";
    }
    explore.style.cursor="pointer";
    explore.style.cursor="hand";
}
function outTitle(div) {
    if (div!= isClicked) {
        div.style.background="#eb56bd";
    }
    if (titleClicked == false) {
        div.style.display="none";
        news.style.display="none";
        about.style.display="none";
        events.style.display="none";
    }
}
function titleClick(div) {
    div.style.background="#b0408d";
    var isClicked = div;

    if (div == news) 
    {
        about.style.background="#eb56bd";
        events.style.background="#eb56bd";
        newsContent.style.display="block";
        aboutContent.style.display="none";
        eventsContent.style.display="none";
    }
    else if (div == about)
    {
        news.style.background="#eb56bd";
        events.style.background="#eb56bd";
        newsContent.style.display="none";
        aboutContent.style.display="block";
        eventsContent.style.display="none";

    }
    else
    {
        news.style.background="#eb56bd";
        about.style.background="#eb56bd";
        newsContent.style.display="none";
        aboutContent.style.display="none";
        eventsContent.style.display="block";
    }
    explore.style.top="5%";
    news.style.top="5%";
    about.style.top="5%";
    events.style.top="5%";
    titleClicked=true;
}
</script>    
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks so much for your help.

A secondary issue:  how do I prevent the cursor from changing from the pointer when directed at the text in my menu?

Thank again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never managed to get the pseudo-classes (like `:hover`) to behave the way you want.  If you can use jQuery, you can add a click function to the menu class:

```
$('.title').click(function() {
$('.title').css({'background':'#eb56bd'});
$(this).css({'background':'#b0408d'});
});
```

First you set all backgrounds to the non-clicked color, then apply the highlight color to the clicked item.  This ensure a previously clicked item has the highlight removed when you click on another item.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XQA6y/)

Answer (score 1):

You should use css classes to style your menu links:

```
.selected{background:rgb(176, 64, 141);}
```

When a menu link is clicked, then you apply the selected class to the that menu link

```
function titleClick(div) {
   //div.style.background="#b0408d";
   div.className='selected';
   var isClicked = div;
```

Following that you'll need to clear the 'selected' class from the other menu links so that they are no longer selected, example:

```
about.className="";
events.className="";
```

Instead of using mouseover and mouse out to style your menu links, use css :hover instead:

```
#news:hover{
    background:"#eb56bd";
}
```

As for the div not showing, I'm guessing it's because the divs are empty. I've filled it up with some random text and it does show.

Comment: Thank you, your idea about the div was correct.  However, using the class did not keep the title link highlighted after it was clicked.  Do you have any other ideas?  I can edit my question to include my changed code if that would help.